# Issue with mail merge rejecting high-content rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-word-2016, mail-merge

I have a mail merge creating word documents from a (macro-enabled) workbook of 77 columns (two sheets - one for dropping raw data into and another that does some cleanup before the mail merge).  I originally had an issue with the mail merge arbitrarily truncating some of the text fields.  After doing some research, I changed the connection type from the default (OLE DB) to DDE and created a named range in my source spreadsheet to point to.  This solved the truncation issue, but created another issue that I am stumped on.

The third record in my source data contains some long blocks of text.  Originally (with OLE DB connection) mail merge handled this row without issue.  With the new DDE connection, mail merge loads the first two records and then stops, refusing to load the third row or any subsequent rows.  If I arbitrarily delete the contents of some of the cells in the third row, it will load the entire record set.  It does not seem to matter which cells I delete from as long as I delete enough of them.  The row contains roughly 23,000 characters in total across all the columns.

Is there a hidden size limit to rows using this method?  Is there any way around this issue for large records?